# Microsoft Emotion API for video with Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using the following code to send my video and apparently I got no error. But the response is coming blank. How can I read the response?

```
########### Python 2.7 #############
import httplib, urllib, base64, json

headers = {
    # Request headers
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'

}

video_filename = {"url":"https://fsarquivoeastus.blob.core.windows.net/public0/WhatsApp-Video-20160727.mp4"}
params = urllib.urlencode({})


try:
    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.projectoxford.ai')
    conn.request("POST", "/emotion/v1.0/recognizeinvideo?%s" % params,     json.dumps(video_filename), headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    print(data)
    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```

Answer (score 1):

The Cognitive Service Video APIs, including Emotion, operate asynchronously, and by design return an empty response body when the POST succeeds.  What you must do instead is retrieve the operation URL from the headers, as shown here:

```
response = conn.getresponse()
location = response.getheader('operation-location');
print(location);
```

You call GET on that `location` URL to check on the status of the operation.  More on that [here](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/5639d931ca73072154c1ce89/operations/56f8d4471984551ec0a0984f).

Answer (score 0):

@FelipeSouzaLima, To getting the operation result from Emotion Recognition in Video, you need to do two steps as below.

1. Call the REST API for [Emotion Recognition in Video](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/5639d931ca73072154c1ce89/operations/56f8d40e1984551ec0a0984e), then you will get the blank response body and the `operation-location` header which will be called at the next step as @cthrash said.
2. Call the url of the value of `operation-location` header above with the same `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` as request header, then you can get the json response body which includes the recognition job status. If the value of `status` field in the json response is `Succeeded`, you will get the operation result as `processingResult` field in the json result, please refer to the REST API of [Get Recognition in Video Operation Result](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/5639d931ca73072154c1ce89/operations/56f8d4471984551ec0a0984f).